# How to get UnoSliderDemo.Wasm to run on MacOS?

Tags: uno-platform

Building debug with Uno 3.7.0-dev.195.  Build appears to work, but execution fails looking for UnoSliderDemo.Wasm/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/UnoSliderDemo.Wasm.runtimeconfig.json.  Where do I get this file?

MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3
Visual Studio for Mac 8.9